# tabs are displayed wrongly in IE7,float:left doesn't work as expected

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

The **Preview**, **What others are saying** tabs are stacked and right-aligned (wrong).

They should be horizontal and left-aligned.

It's displayed correctly in firefox,IE8.

What's the reason for this?

URL: http://www.learncentral.org/resource/view/59896

**UPDATE**

Related html here:

```
<div class="ed_tabs">
      <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
        <li class="selected ui-tabs-selected"><a href="#first">Preview</a></li>
        <li><a href="#second">What others are saying...(0)</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.ed_tabs {
border-bottom:3px solid #3F79C2;
float:left;
width:100%;
}

.ed_tabs ul {
float:left;
list-style:none outside none;
margin:0.5em 0 0;
padding:0 0 0 1em;
}

li  {
float:left;
padding:0 1px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code in question here, not just a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why IE7 is working differently, but I see that your CSS rule for

```
.ed_tabs ul li a
```

does a `float:right` to the anchor (A).  Try changing this to `float: left` instead.

Comment: I don't have a real answer, other than to say that IE7 does things differently.  FWIW, I tried this in an ancient version of Mozilla and it exhibits the same problem.  The `float:left` solution does seem to fix the problem in IE7 so you might want to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks,a better try may be delete the `float` setting on `a`,though:)

Comment: Sure, that might work too.  BTW, if this information was helpful, feel free to mark this as answered.  Thanks...